# Authentication Type invisible in "Edit Authentication" Window (Central Administration 2010)

Tags: authentication, central-administration

I am facing a strange issue in Central Administration. I was trying to change the Authentication Type of a Web Application by following the steps, Central Administration -> Manage Web Application -> Authentication Providers -> Default -> Edit Authentication, but the "Authentication Type" option is invisible here. For other web applications it shows but for the web application that I am concerned with, does not shows. Here is the image:

[image]

**This is missing in the above window:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your current Authentication Type is Windows then you see the outdated section with

- Windows
- Forms
- Web single sign on

But isn't allowed to change it as the only real options are:

- Windows
- Claims

If your current Authentication Type is Claims then the section isn't shown.

My guess regarding the reason behind this is:

- It was planned to give you support for changing Windows => Claims in the UI, but they didn't get it completed, so we only see an odd part in the UI
- Changing Claims => Windows isn't supported so there should be no ui for this

Comment: Hi Jakobsen,
You are absolutely correct, the Authentication Type was changed to Claim Based but now how can I revert to Windows Based authentication?

Comment: As far as I know it's not supported. So I'd recommend deleting the WebApp (not content databases), Create new WebApp, Attach databases, change permissions.

Comment: That means I have to take a backup of the Content DB and then delete the Web App and then create a new web app and restore and attach the content DB to it.

Comment: If when deleting the Web App you leave the "Delete content databases" as No then the restore part isn't needed. (The backup is still a good idea)

Comment: Isn't this solution requiring a script that call `MigrateUser` ? (because of the claims prefix)

Comment: The `MigrateUser` doesn't support converting from Claim to Classic. So that's why my step was "Change Permissions"

Answer (score 0):

If you go in Security > Specify authentication providers, the result is still the same?

Comment: Hi Seb,
The result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your replies and answers.

I also found two solutions:

1. Delete the web application without deleting the content database, then create a new Windows authenticated web application and connect the new web application to the old content database. (This was already advised by @Per Jakobsen above)
2. Use the script below to change Claim Based Authentication to Classic mode authentication. “Authentication Type” section will be visible in the “Edit Authentication” page after you run the commands. In this method, the existing sites will be inaccessible with the old credentials. You need to set up all the accounts for Windows authentication from scratch.

   ```
          $setcba = Get-SPWebApplication "http://YourSiteURL"

          $setcba.UseClaimsAuthentication = 0;

          $setcba.Update()
   ```

You should backup the web application before either of the actions above to avoid any data loss and make sure we can go back to the current state.

Thanks & Best Regards,